# eBay API additem returns error when creating Buy It Now listing

Tags: ebay-api

I am using the following code to list items in eBay through their API. However, the code below only creates auction type listings.

I was just wondering if anyone knows how I can create buy it now items/listings instead?

Thank You

This is my XML request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AddItemRequest
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>AgAAAA</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <Version>949</Version>
    <Item>
        <Site>US</Site>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>45114</CategoryID>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <ItemSpecifics>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Brand</Name>
                <Value>Unbranded</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>MPN</Name>
                <Value>Does Not Apply</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Model</Name>
                <Value>mp02</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Country/Region of Manufacture</Name>
                <Value>United States</Value>
            </NameValueList>
        </ItemSpecifics>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <BuyItNowPrice currencyID="USD">30.00</BuyItNowPrice>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>Auction</ListingType>
        <LiveAuction>TRUE</LiveAuction>
        <LotSize>11</LotSize>
        <Location>san jose, CA</Location>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>usasiva@gmail.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <PictureDetails>
            <PictureURL>http://www.qbforms.com/api/shopfunc/Penguins.jpg</PictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <RegionID>0</RegionID>
        <StartPrice>20.00</StartPrice>
        <ShippingTermsInDescription>True</ShippingTermsInDescription>
        <Title>tak_test2_31</Title>
        <Description>itemXYZzx</Description>
        <ReturnPolicy>
            <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
            <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
            <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost>2.0</ShippingServiceCost>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
        </ShippingDetails>
    </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and you are trying to create a *Buy it Now* listing instead of an *auction* listing, then it's simple: you just need to use a different API call `AddFixedPriceItem`.

[Here is the API reference](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/AddFixedPriceItem.html) with all the details.

Comment: Thank You for replying , But this AddFixedPriceItem api add item under fixedprice i want add item in auction.